# Would this call for Javascript in AS3 work?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, actionscript-3

```
stop();

import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

ExternalInterface.addCallback("quarter1call", quarter1call);
function quarter1call():void
{
    gotoAndPlay(2);
}
```

Would the above script work when attached to a javascript that calls for the 'quarter1call()' function? I am not sure how to code the javascript side of this relationship and I am thus unable to test it, if you could provide any help with that side or just explain if this would work it would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is placed on the first frame of an animation, where it is stopped and resumed on the second frame.

Comment: I would wrap the ExternalInterface code inside a if(ExternalInterface.available){}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, this would work fine. The `addCallback` function exposes your `quarter1call()` function to the Javascript side of things under the highly unlikely name `"quarter1call"` ;-)

Depending on how your SWF is embedded in the HTML page, you can call the function using something like this (make sure the HTML element is loaded first):

```
document.getElementById('idOfSwfElement').quarter1call();
```

where the HTML resembles:

```
<embed src="foo.swf" id="idOfSwfElement" />
```